# How to log to DevTools console in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get a similar effect as JavaScipt's `console.log("this is a message")` or `console.error("this is an error!")` in ASP.net?

`Console.Log()` in C# get's swallowed in the abyss, and who knows where `Console.Out` goes to, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: C# is server sided, so your Console.WriteLine() is shown in the Visual Studio Console.

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn However is there a way to get the a Console.WriteLine or Console.Out to go into DevTool's console?

Comment: As I said. Every C# Code only gets executed at the Server. The Code generates your HTML and then the user gets this HTML. When you want an output in DevTools, it has to be Javascript